# CRM C# "The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota."

Tags: c#, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I get the error "The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota." when I try to make a delete request managed solution.

```cs
var queryImportedSolution = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "solution",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "solutionid" }),
    Criteria = new FilterExpression()
};

queryImportedSolution.Criteria.AddCondition("uniquename", ConditionOperator.Equal, "qaddressForMicrosoftCRM");
var ImportedSolution = sdkSvc.RetrieveMultiple(queryImportedSolution).Entities[0];

sdkSvc.Delete("solution", ImportedSolution.Id);
```

Comment: what is your trigger for this plugin?

Comment: manually launched by the user from powershell with a request